# Can PyPy use multiple CPUs in one process?

Tags: python, pypy, gil

There is a GIL in CPython, and I heard that PyPy does not have that problem. Is this true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, PyPy still has a GIL. Jython and IronPython don't. However, there is an effort to replace it with STM, see http://pypy.org/tmdonate.html for details.